# android - display image from gallery

Tags: android, imageview

I have several images stored in content://media/external/images/media. I would like to display by using ImageView and add the image view to the table. here is my code.

```
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 24;
            final Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("content://media"+getFileLocation(), options);
            ImageView milestoneImageView = new ImageView(this);
            milestoneImageView.setImageBitmap(b);
            recordRow.addView(milestoneImageView);
```

When I print out the getFileLocation(), it says "/external/images/media/62". So I added "content://media" to make a full path, but it is not working...

Can someone point out why the code above is not working?

Comment: For now, I am just trying to display only one image for testing purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `"/external/images/media/62"` its a Uri not a real file path..

So instead of

`final Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("content://media"+getFileLocation(), options);`

Just try

```
final Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream("content://media"+getFileLocation()), null,options);
```

And let me know what happen..